# How can I reduce the LibCef.dll size for install package

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am using the CefSharp Chromium Browser in a WINFORM application and I have been told that I need to include a few files for my installation to work properly. I have done this and my app works like a charm. Problem is that my install package is now over 80 MB due to LibCef.dll being over 100 MB in size.

Is there any way to make my install package smaller?

I am developing my APP in VS2019 and have seen in a few posts that I can go into the DLL ( not sure how ) and remove what I do not need. I have no clue on how to do any of this and would really appreciate any direction as that one DLL is larger than my entire application.

Am I reading the other posts correctly or am I really stuck with a 100MB DLL in my install package?

Comment: You can try https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/portableapps.com_appcompactor the last time i tried upx compression the resulting libcef.dll was unusable https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3094 officially I don't believe there is a supported method of reducing the size. Remembering that CefSharp is just one of many chromium embedded framework wrappers. Libcef.dll comes from https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/master/

Comment: So, as I want to use Chromium Browser, I am stuck with a very large install file?

Comment: The short answer is yes. You can try one of the upx based compression tools. They might with luck have resolved whatever the issue is. You can use an installer that supports delta/binary diff updates to reduce size.

Comment: i used upx compressor for libcef.dll but that it givens an error that "BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=87.1.132.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138"